# Can I replace (Date.current - created_at.to_date).to_i <= number_of_days with number_of_days.days.ago.to_date? Is it a good idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my models/book.rb I have this

```
  def created_since?(number_of_days)
    (Date.current - created_at.to_date).to_i <= number_of_days
  end
```

That is used in view files like

```
<% if @book.created_since?(30) %>
```

Can I optimize it editing with something like this?

```
  def created_since?(number_of_days)
    number_of_days.days.ago.to_date
  end
```

Is it a good idea? will it work the same?

Comment: Any method followed by question mark should return a boolean. Your last implementation of the method does not seem to make any comparison and therefore return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

To subtract days from a date, it's easiest to work with dates. I would try something like this, from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Date/Subtract61daysfromadate.htm):

```
def created_since?(number_of_days)
  created_at.to_date >= Date.now - number_of_days
end
```

The only downside of this is it will not be precise to the minute, if you did want this accuracy you'll need to edit the Time rather than the Date:

```
def created_since?(number_of_days)
  created_at >= Time.now - (number_of_days * 24 * 60 * 60)
end
```

This takes the number of days, converts it into seconds, and then uses that to find the correct cut off point.

Comment: is created_at.to_date >= Date.now - number_of_days faster than mine?